# How can I melt your face?

Tags: achievements, borderlands

In Borderlands there is an in-game trophy system. The very first trophy is titled **12 Days of Pandora** and involves killing lots of things in many different specific ways. One of these ways is apparently face melting, as I'm currently listed to have 1\2 of my "Faces Melted" entry. I have no idea how I got the one I already have, and would very much like to re-create the event, as completing this entry will finish this trophy for me.

*How do I melt faces?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'Melt faces' is a euphemism for corrosive kills, analogous to kill x enemies with fire/shock/explosives. Use corrosive weapons or corrosive barrels.

Comment: Could you please put additional detail into your answer, such as what color corrosive barrels are, or a screenshot example of a corrosive weapon?

Comment: @ender http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Corrosive

Comment: Seems a bit redundant, but sure: corrosive weapons are green. You point the business end of a weapon at the enemy and pull the trigger. Don't forget you need ammo to shoot.